# Why is PHP not running

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-http-server

I have ubuntu 14.04 desktop, I have apache2 php5 and all those packages installed.
Yet PHP scripts won't run..
My site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin seven@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/seven/html

<Directory "/home/seven/html">
    php_admin_flag engine on
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I've tried tons of different combinations. I hope it's just a stupid mistake in this code.

Comment: What packages did you install exactly? Also, this is not the full site configuration, is it? Is PHP installed successfully? Can you run `php -v`? How are you determining that it's "not working"? What are you opening in your browser? What file are you using for testing? Please give us a little more details to work with.

Comment: I have apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt installed. It is but I accidentally left out </VirtualHost> from the copy. Yes I can run php -v, I have PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4. http://sevenofnine24.noip.me/phpinfo.php this file only has "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" in it.

Comment: thanks for the answers found solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Comment: You should post the full answer (not just a link, but the actual steps) here on your question. That way others will find it more easily

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to install a lamp server on a debian based system is to simply run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
tasksel install lamp-server
```

It does all the configuration for you.
But you should still learn how it all interconnects.

After you can open up /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default and add/alter your virtual hosts.